# Reversing the order of displayed numbers in a nested loop

Tags: java, nested-loops

I've been doing some solo exercises to prepare for starting college next year and this one is stumping. The output is current

```
   1
  12
 123
1234
```

and I want to get it to

```
   1
  21
 321
4321
```

Here's the code I've been playing with for a while.

```
Scanner stdIn = new Scanner (System.in);
int n;

do
{
    System.out.println("Please enter the value number: ");
    n = stdIn.nextInt();
}
while  ( n < 1 || n > 9);
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
     for (int k = i; k < n ; k++)  
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    } 
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)  
    {
        System.out.print(j);
    }
    System.out.println(); 
}

stdIn.close();
```

Comment: There are some articles in the web, one of them is https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/examples/reverse-number 
which tells about how to reverse a number, you can make use of that while iterating over the input numbers

Comment: This is a good learning opportunity. Think about the problem. Run through your program in your head, or work through it on paper. Which part of it needs to be changed? Can you narrow it down to a particular line of code? You'll learn more if you stick with it and figure it out yourself than if we tell you the answer.

Comment: If you try the old guess-and-check method, avoid making blind modifications. After you change something try to predict what will happen before you run the program. Make predictions. It's the scientific method, essentially: you want to formulate a hypothesis before you run your experiment.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to make the second for loop *start from `i`*, and go down to 1:

```
for (int j = i; j >= 1; j--)
{
    System.out.print(j);
}
```

Alternatively, print `i - j + 1`:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
{
    System.out.print(i - j + 1);
}
```

Also, you should not close the `Scanner`, which is "connected to" `System.in` You didn't open `System.in`, so don't close it.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the numbers to String and print its reverse:

```
Scanner stdIn = new Scanner (System.in);
int n;
String str;
do
{
    System.out.println("Please enter the value number: ");
    n = stdIn.nextInt();
}
while  ( n < 1 || n > 9);
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
     str = "";
     for (int k = i; k < n ; k++)  
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    } 
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)  
    {
        str = str + j;
    }
    System.out.println(new StringBuffer(str).reverse().toString()); 
}

stdIn.close();
```